# What is the significance of x in the address of a variable?

Tags: c++, memory-address

I am trying to print the address of a data member of a class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test { int x; };

int main() {
    test t;
    std::cout << &t.x << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

> 0x23fe4c

I don't understand how this points to a memory address. I want to know the meaning of this way of representing addresses.

Comment: `0x` is not part of the address, it means the output is in hexadecimal. That would be `2358860` in decimal.

Comment: what is the use of `0`  before `x` ?

Comment: the character sequence `0x` indicates the integer literal is in hexadecimal. see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `0x` (or sometimes `0X`) prefix indicates that the value following is presented as a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) value, i.e. is represented in base (or radix) 16 instead of base 10 as decimal values. For example, `0x1234abcd` means 1234abcd<sub>16</sub> which is written as a decimal is 305441741<sub>10</sub> or simply 305441741. This is simply one common representation used for memory addresses and other computer- or programming-related contexts.